# How to create virtual host in nginx server ? and ajax call

Tags: php, mysql

I am using WT-NMP software with combination of php,mysql and ngnix server.

```
worker_processes  1;




events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

        server_tokens       off;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    ssi         off;

    #Timeouts
        client_body_timeout 5;
        client_header_timeout   5;
        keepalive_timeout   25 25;
        send_timeout        15s;
    resolver_timeout    3s;

    #Directive sets timeout period for connection with FastCGI-server. It should be noted that this value can't exceed 75 seconds. 
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 5s;

    #Directive sets the amount of time for upstream to wait for a fastcgi process to send data. Change this directive if you have long running fastcgi processes that do not produce output until they have finished processing. If you are seeing an upstream timed out error in the error log, then increase this parameter to something more appropriate. 
    fastcgi_read_timeout    40s;

    #Directive specifies request timeout to the server. The timeout is calculated between two write operations, not for the whole request. If no data have been written during this period then serve closes the connection.
    fastcgi_send_timeout    15s;


    fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    #fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    #fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

    open_file_cache off;


    #php max upload limit cannot be larger than this       
    client_max_body_size 8m;
        ####client_body_buffer_size  1K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;   
    types_hash_max_size 2048;




    include nginx.mimetypes.conf;
    default_type text/html;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##
    access_log "c:/wt-nmp/log/nginx_access.log";
    error_log "c:/wt-nmp/log/nginx_error.log" warn; #debug or warn
    log_not_found on;  #enables or disables messages in error_log about files not found on disk. 
    rewrite_log off;

    #Leave this off
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;


    gzip  off;

    index  index.php index.htm index.html;

    server {
        listen      127.0.0.1:80    default_server;
        listen      127.0.0.1:8080;
        #listen     [::1]:80    ipv6only=on;        

        server_name  mylocalhost;

        root "c:/wt-nmp/www/projectname";

        autoindex on;
        error_log  "c:/wt-nmp/log/nginx_error.log";

        allow       127.0.0.1;
        #allow      ::1;
        deny        all;

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }


        #tools are now served from wt-nmp/include/tools/
        location ~ ^/tools/.*\.php$ {                   
            root "c:/wt-nmp/include";
            try_files $uri =404; 
            include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
        }
        location ~ ^/tools/ {
            root "c:/wt-nmp/include";
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404; 
                fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
            include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
            }



    }



    include domains.d/*.conf;


    include nginx.phpfarm.conf;



}
```

when I am trying to access with "mylocalhost" its working fine when I am firing an event and call ajax method . It is giving page not found message

Comment: can you open the request url directly in browser? Are you sure path is valid? Not much information provided about request itself

Answer (score 0):

[WT-NMP - portable Nginx Mysql Php development stack for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtnmp) README.md states:

> Starting only one PHP-CGI server with wt-nmp.exe --phpCgiServers=1 will result in slow ajax requests since Nginx will not be able to process PHP scripts simultaneous.

So, make sure you use the latest version of WT-NMP and choose at least 3 PHP-CGI servers.